# How does gcc std::set use stl_tree.h to store node keys?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, set, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement some STL containers as an exercise.

I have implemented a red-black-tree that takes as template parameter the type of the `Key` that the nodes will store. This has been enough to implement a `set`, but now that I'm trying to implement a `map`, I need the red-black-tree to store key and value.

I've seen the implementation for the `std::set` and `std::map` in the GNU docs and both use the same `stl_tree.h` file. That red-black tree implementation uses a `_Key` and `_Val` as template parameters:

```cpp
00326   template<typename _Key, typename _Val, typename _KeyOfValue,
00327            typename _Compare, typename _Alloc = allocator<_Val> >
00328     class _Rb_tree
00329     {
00330       typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Rb_tree_node<_Val> >::other
00331               _Node_allocator;
00332 
00333     protected:
00334       typedef _Rb_tree_node_base* _Base_ptr;
00335       typedef const _Rb_tree_node_base* _Const_Base_ptr;
00336       typedef _Rb_tree_node<_Val> _Rb_tree_node;
00337 
00338     public:
00339       typedef _Key key_type;
00340       typedef _Val value_type;
00341       typedef value_type* pointer;
```

from: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__tree_8h-source.html

However, the `std::set` implementation just stores a `Key` and uses a typedef to define `value_type` as `_Key`.

```cpp
00106   template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc>
00107     class set
00108     {
00109       // concept requirements
00110       typedef typename _Alloc::value_type                   _Alloc_value_type;
00111       __glibcxx_class_requires(_Key, _SGIAssignableConcept)
00112       __glibcxx_class_requires4(_Compare, bool, _Key, _Key,
00113                 _BinaryFunctionConcept)
00114       __glibcxx_class_requires2(_Key, _Alloc_value_type, _SameTypeConcept)  
00115 
00116     public:
00117       // typedefs:
00118       //@{
00119       /// Public typedefs.
00120       typedef _Key     key_type;
00121       typedef _Key     value_type;
00122       typedef _Compare key_compare;
00123       typedef _Compare value_compare;
00124       typedef _Alloc   allocator_type;
00125       //@}
00126 
00127     private:
00128       typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Key>::other _Key_alloc_type;
00129 
00130       typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Identity<value_type>,
00131                key_compare, _Key_alloc_type> _Rep_type;
00132       _Rep_type _M_t;  // red-black tree representing set
```

from: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__set_8h-source.html

(Also `map`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__map_8h-source.html)

That would be equivalent to `_Rb_tree<key_type, key_type, ...` . Does that mean that the `std::set` stores the same key two times?

I know I could just implement another red-black-tree whose nodes store a key and a value and change the `find` method to recive the `key` as parameter and return the `value`. That would be enough to implement a map at this moment, but now I'm curious about the real `std` implementation of the red-black-tree. How is  this behaviour achieved?

Comment: In `std::set`, the data is its own key.  In a map, it stores `std::pair<key, value>` as the element, and only applies comparison on the key part of the pair.

Comment: The "trick" is in the `_KeyOfValue` parameter, which can extract the key part of the stored item. Either the first part of the pair for a map, or the entire key if  it is a set.

Comment: *_Rb_tree<key_type, key_type, ... . Does that mean that the std::set stores the same key two times?* No, it just means that the key type and the value type are the same. The tree only stores the value type (in both cases).